# Qt - Inheriting a Class from a Base Class

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I'm making a snake game with Qt, and so far I have not once been successful in inheriting one of my classes from another one of my classes. I can get my classes to inherit from Qt classes like `QObject` or `QGraphicsRectItem`, but not from my own.

Here is an example of this problem, along with its error message:

```
#ifndef SNAKE_H
#define SNAKE_H

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QKeyEvent>

class Head;
class Food;
class Base; //Error 1

class Snake: public QGraphicsView, public Base //Error 2
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    const static int width = 820;
    const static int height = 500;

public:
    Snake();
    QGraphicsScene * scene;
    QGraphicsView * view;
    QGraphicsRectItem * border;
    QGraphicsRectItem * border2;

};

#endif // SNAKE_H

////// Errors /////////
/*

Error 1:
  forward declaration of 'class Base'
   class Base;
         ^

Error 2: 
  invalid use of incomplete type 'class Base'
   class Snake: public QGraphicsView, public Base
                                             ^

*/
```

So what exactly am I doing wrong here? Why won't it inherit properly and why won't it let me make a forward declaration of `class Base`?

Thanks!

Comment: You need the full class definition in order to inherit from it.

Comment: @Niel Kirk - What do you mean by that?

Comment: My name is Neil Kirk. I mean that whether you have `class Base { stuff };` it needs to be provided to the compiler before you inherit from it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `class Base` you need to include the header file containing the `Base` class (i.e. `#include "Base.h"`)

Answer (score 0):

```
invalid use of incomplete type 'class Base' class Snake: public QGraphicsView, public Base
```

Compiler errors might often be obscure, but this one isn't. You can't use a forward declared class, unless for pointers to it. That includes inheriting it as well. You need to have the class you are inheriting beforehand, either by having it in the source or including it.